# How to create a Shield TV APP with phonegap build

Tags: phonegap-build, android-tv

How can i install Shield TV support in Phonegap build?

when i add this to my config.xml

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
```

i get this error message

```
Error - Malformed config.xml - You can fix this here
```

Any ideas what i making wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id          = "com.xxxx.app"
        versionCode = "1.0.9" 
        version     = "1.0.9" >

    <!-- versionCode is Android only -->
    <!-- version is in major.minor.patch format --> 
    <name>XXX</name>

    <description>
XXX
    </description>

    <author href="xxxxx" email="contact@xxx.com">
        XXX
    </author>

    <icon src="icon.png" />

    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />

    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />

    <access origin="*" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />    

    <!-- Intenet zugriff plugin -->
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm"/>

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm"/>

    <!--- <plugin name="cordova-plugin-fullscreen" source="npm" /> -->
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" source="npm" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" source="npm" />
    <plugin name="phonegap-admob" source="npm"/>

</widget>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, try to check this [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/#The%20Basics) on how to properly build the PhoneGap.

You can check here the Essential Properties and Example of config.xml

I also found here in this [Failed Builds](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/support/failed-builds/) that if you encountered an error Malformed config.xml, you can use the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check whether your config.xml is a valid XML.